# how do we calculate the memory usage for different data sizes for algorithms implemented in python

Tags: python, memory

I have different datasets with different sizes and I want to calculate the memory usage of the sorting algorithms implemented in Python against these data sets. For each type of sorting algorithms,I want to know the memory usage for each data set so that I can plot a graph.

I tried using psutil.virtual_memory() but it is not giving the expected results.

I tried to install heapy but anaconda is telling me that no such library exists.

Comment: have you tried using pip to install heapy?

Comment: I tried 'conda install heapy' and i get the error message that 'the package is not available from current channels'.

Comment: I don't personally use Conda, but I know that pip will work to install heapy.  I just tried it on my computer and it was able to find it.  If you want I can show you how to install pip, or try to figure out another way to get it?

Comment: Yes, I tried the same and it worked with pip install. But my code is as below:
def getMemory():
    hp=hpy()
    before=hp.heap()
    insertionSort(dataset)
    after=hp.heap()
    leftover=after-before
    print(leftover)
But I am getting an error that 'module object is not callable' for hp=hpy() line

Comment: I realize what you mean, here is a different repo that works better with python3 (I assume that is what you are using, but this works for both).  It is called `pympler`, it installed and ran for me fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend checking out [memory_profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory_profiler/). A profiler that can output the line by line memory consumption of a Python function. It can be installed by running `pip install -U memory_profiler` and it seems pretty simple to use. Simply add a `@profile` over the function you would like to monitor and run `python -m memory_profiler YourScript.py` to start monitoring. memory_profiler also comes with a auto-plotter executable, mprof. More information on mprof can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/memory_profiler/) and [here](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2014/plot-memory-usage-as-a-function-of-time/).

You can also write the memory_profiler output to a file using:

```
fp=open('memory_profiler.log','w+')
@profile(stream=fp)
```

And by importing the module in the script itself, you can avoid calling `-m memory_profiler` all together: `from memory_profiler import profile`

If that doesn't quite fit the bill, I'd recommend checking out [this help full little blog](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-profile-memory-usage-in-python).

Comment: How do I run it if I want  to save the memory usage in the program to plot it.

Comment: @Sree it looks like memory_profiler also comes with an auto-plotter executable **mprof**. Running `mprof run YourScript.py` with the `@profile` decorator in your script will generate a time based plot for you. You can also write the output to a file by adding `fp=open('memory_profiler.log','w+')` above `@profile(stream=fp)`. More info can be found at the [memory_profiler project page](https://pypi.org/project/memory_profiler/) and more info about mprof can be found at this [blog](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2014/plot-memory-usage-as-a-function-of-time/)

Comment: looks like memory_profiler %memit in jupyter notebooks works only for that particular data cell like %memit np.zeroes(50,1). But what if I want to measure the memory usage for a module.I tried giving %memit as the first line of the module but there is no result.

Comment: %memit is actually giving me the peak memory but not the total memory used by the module. Also, how should use @profile decorator,I couldn't find a good information on that.

Comment: @Sree As the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/memory_profiler/) says, "if you use IPython, you can use the %mprun, %%mprun, %memit and %%memit magics", so using it without IPython may not give the desired result.

Comment: @Sree I agree, there does seem to be a lack of documentation. After digging around at the [source](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/blob/master/memory_profiler.py), it appears that it is possible to run memory_profiler on a module `def run_module_with_profiler(module, profiler, backend, passed_args=[]):` (line1134). Also in the source, it appears there are 4 possible arguments for @profile. `profile(func=FunctionToProfile, stream=LocationOfOutput, precision=PrecisionToDisplayMB, backend="BackendMonitor")` Default backend is psutil. You may find more with help(memory_profiler)

Comment: Are jupyter notebooks not IPython. I am not aware of any difference. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sree I'm really not sure, don't think I've ever used jupyter notebooks. If they do, then it may be a bug.